trying to create a file from android kotlin fails with: Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key error
this code used to work until a couple of days ago.
it still works in the debug version, but not in the release anymore.
no updates have been done to SDK or gradle.
the oauth apps are correctly set in google console, the correct SHA1 keys are entered.
now it just fails with:

Error during GoogleDriveManager.uploadFile operation:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key error

suspend fun uploadFile(credential: GoogleAccountCredential, file: File): Date? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            try {
                val drive =  Drive.Builder(
                        NetHttpTransport(),
                        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                        credential
                )
                .setApplicationName(string(R.string.app_name))
                .build()

                val googleDriveFile = GoogleDriveFile()
                googleDriveFile.name = file.name

                val fileContent = FileContent("text/txt", file)

                drive.Files().create(googleDriveFile, fileContent).execute()

                Date()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                log {
                    "Error during GoogleDriveManager.uploadFile operation: ${exception}"
                }

                null
            }
        }
    }


can you double check your proguard file? If the issue is happening only on release mode, it's most likely to do with your proguard configuration

standard settings: proguardFiles(
getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
"proguard-rules.pro"
) proguard-rules.pro is empty. i removed the settings, the same

i cannot belive that google (or jetbrains, whoever) are releasing software like this: the solution was to set isMinifyEnabled and isShrinkResources to false. having any of them on true makes the google drive api not work ... in my case

If you set minifyEnabled =false, you will disable proguard.

Disabling minification (minifyEnabled =false) will disable proguard. If you do that, then you can't protect your source code from decompilation. If you do that, there's nothing to protect your source code from hackers stealing your work. Please don't do that.

Not to mention the attack surface will become much wider, considering a hacker can see your source code, api keys, etc. Please find another solution. But the issue is your proguard file. Please post an issue for Google to look at on their repos

i know that ... but i was using the default proguard file, the one in the project is empty

finally got it working, i included the content of this file:
proguard-google-api-client.txt and this line:
-keep class com.google.api.services.drive.** { *; }

thanks to on Dan Gerchcovich to pointing out the security issues by disabled obfuscations. while i knew them, i would have happily turn it off just to make it work :)
